An animated kids' film with a colonel (not 101 Dalmatians)
When I was a kid my mother read me bedtime stories, some of them adapted from popular children's films (possibly Little Golden Books). One of these books was an adaptation of a Disney or Disney-esque (perhaps Don Bluth) animated film featuring talking animals, which had a character whose name I recall as Colonel Pinky, or perhaps Colonel Pink, and I believe he was a villain, but possibly not the main villain. However, this is obviously not the right name, because Google turns up nothing relevant.
I remember this because I made my mother pronounce the word "colonel" the way it's spelled, because at the time I refused to believe it could be pronounced "kernel". Later, I got to see the film the book was based on. There I found out that my mother was right and I was wrong about the pronunciation of "colonel".
Given my age, I would say the upper bound for this event would be around 1995. Later than that and I think I'd have been too old to be read bedtime stories. Back then I think it wasn't terribly uncommon for certain films to be re-released in theaters from time to time, or it might have been on TV, so I don't know if we can put a lower bound on the movie's original release date.
From what little I remember of the movie and the character, I would be convinced the character is Carface Carruthers from All Dogs Go to Heaven, except I cannot find any evidence he or anyone else in the movie is ever called "colonel". (The TV series spun off from that movie did once feature a colonel, but I have never seen the series or even been aware of its existence until recently, and I do not recognize the character from his appearance.)

I think you're thinking of Colonel Hathi (sounds like pinky) from Jungle Book. He sort of looks like Carface in that they both have a fat grey head.

However, if memory serves, Hathi was disagreeable but wasn't an antagonist. Aside from that it fits the description and time range and has been made into hundreds of children's books.

A good guess, but that's not it. Sorry. :/
